# calldata usage, difference between the method calling function with calldata

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, calldata, rollups

I recently studied optimism, and found that `appendSequencerBatch()` of CanonicalTransactionChain contract called with calldata. I assumed that this function was called using

```
0x(functionSelector)+(data..)
```

One question arose here, what is difference between above and call
`appendSequencerBatch(bytes calldata data)`?

Both calling methods seem to have the same effects and usage, don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference; you are correct in assuming that this function was called in such a way: indeed `calldata` includes the function selector and data to be passed to that function.